# IntelliJ GitHub: GitHub user profile not set

Tags: github, intellij-idea

Has anyone encountered following difficulties with IntelliJ GitHub version control?
When I push my code up to GitHub, the GitHub will show that it receives a commit from Unknown User.

Comment: Do you get other results when trying to do the same from the command line?

Comment: 1 and 2 seem to be completely different problems. So it is a bad idea to mix them in one question: what would you do if one answer will answer #1 and the other - #2? Which to accept?

Comment: to the question #2: what does local diff show for the commit?

Comment: My primary concern for now is issue 1, although I will open another question for issue 2.

Answer (score 2):

Check if your user.name and user.email are defined correctly - execute this in the folder controlled by Git:

```
git config user.name
```

If it gives your name, and if committing from the command line also is made with correct user name, and if you are on Windows, check if %HOME% environment variable is defined in your system and points to the folder where the global .gitconfig is located.

---

Note: sad that you have given so few details about the problem (no git version, no Intellij IDEA version, no information about the OS); sad that you didn't try or didn't tell us the command line result, but hope it helps.